# react-chart-js-2 keep bar width no matter what the number of bar is

Tags: html, css, reactjs, typescript, chart.js

I'm currently working on a react chart js component, a set of horizontal bar. My goal is to keep the width of the bars at their original size no matter what the number of bar is. (all bar at 30px for instance).

When i add more bars to my component, the general bar width just adapt. I want it to remain the same.

I used the "barThickness" option but when there's too much bars, they just [take all the space](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Enxy0.png) and get hidden by the others (1: the green bar is hidden by the light green one. 2: size of a complete bar)

The canvas size start to get too small and the space between the bars get negative. i want to keep it positive.

```js
import React from "react";
import {HorizontalBar} from 'react-chartjs-2';
import 'chartjs-plugin-error-bars'
import {withTheme,ThemeProps} from "styled-components";
import { 
    Theme
  } from "@material-ui/core";

type Dataset = {
  label: string
  data?: any[]
  backgroundColor: any[]
  borderColor: any[]
  borderWidth: number
}

type Bar = {
  label: string,   // Localication avec un nom explicite
  level: number, // Niveau pour afficher la couleur dans le bench (0> Vert foncé... 4> Rouge foncé)
  value: number,  // Valeur à afficher. Nécessite d'étre dans l'unité et mise en forme (tronquer les décimales...)
}

type PropsType = {
  theme: ThemeProps<Theme>
  title: String
  bars: Bar[]
}

const options = {  
  indexAxis: 'y',
  categorySpacing: 100,
  // Elements options apply to all of the options unless overridden in a dataset
  // In this case, we are setting the border of each horizontal bar to be 2px wide
  elements: {
    bar: {
      borderWidth: 2,
    },
  },
  legend: {
    display: false
  },
  scales: {
    yAxes: [
      {
        ticks: {
          padding: 20
        },
        // categoryPercentage: 0.50, //width en pourcentage
        // barPercentage: 0.50,
        gridLines: {
          color: "transparent",
          drawOnChartArea: false,
          drawTicks: false
        },
      },  
    ],
    xAxes: [
      {
        categoryPercentage: 1.0,
        barPercentage: 1.0,
        gridLines: {
          drawBorder: false,  
          color: "transparent"
        },
        display: false,
        stacked: false, 
      }
    ]
  },
  responsive: true,
  plugins: {
    title: {
      display: true,
      text: 'Cdfùbmknwxcb',
    },
  },
};

class Barchart extends React.Component<PropsType>  {
  data = {
    labels: [],
    datasets: [],
  };

  constructor(props: any) {
    super(props)
    
    this.initialisation()
  }

  initialisation() {
    let dataset  = {} as Dataset;
    dataset.data=[]
    dataset.backgroundColor=[]
    for (var i = 0; i < this.props.bars.length; i++) {
      let bar = this.props.bars[i];
      this.data.labels[i] = bar.label;
      dataset.data[i]=bar.value
      dataset.borderWidth= 0
      //TODO A gérer mieux (librairie car mutualisé avec d'autres composants)
      switch(this.props.bars[i].level) {
      case 0 : 
        dataset.backgroundColor[i]= this.props.theme[0].palette.seuils.verygood;
        break;
      case 1 : 
        dataset.backgroundColor[i]=this.props.theme[0].palette.seuils.good
        break;
      case 2 : 
        dataset.backgroundColor[i]=this.props.theme[0].palette.seuils.medium
        break;
      case 3 : 
        dataset.backgroundColor[i]=this.props.theme[0].palette.seuils.bad
        break;
      case 4 : 
        dataset.backgroundColor[i]=this.props.theme[0].palette.seuils.verybad
        break;
      default : 
        dataset.backgroundColor[i]=this.props.theme[0].palette.seuils.neutral
        break;
      }
    }
    this.data.datasets[0]=dataset;
    this.data.datasets[0].barThickness = 200;
  } 
  render() {
    return (
      <div 
>
        <HorizontalBar data={this.data} options={options}/>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Barchart;
```

a solution would be to increase the size of the canvas when the number of bars increase but i have no clue on how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your chart in a div and then set the height of the div according to the height it needs to be like so:

```js
let DATA_COUNT = Math.max(1, Math.round(Math.random() * 10));
const LABELS = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j"];
const data = {
  labels: [],
  datasets: [{
    backgroundColor: "green",
    data: []
  }]
};

const chart = new Chart("chart", {
  type: "bar",
  data,
  options: {
    responsive: true,
    maintainAspectRatio: false,
    indexAxis: "y",
    plugins: {
      legend: false
    },
    layout: {
      padding: {
        top: 10
      }
    }
  }
});

const div = document.getElementById("container");

function update() {
  DATA_COUNT = Math.max(1, Math.round(Math.random() * 10));
  data.labels = [];
  data.datasets[0].data = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < DATA_COUNT; i++) {
    data.labels.push(LABELS[i]);
    data.datasets[0].data.push(i + 1);
  }
  chart.update();
  const scale = chart.scales.x.height;
  div.style.height = 10 + scale + DATA_COUNT * 20 + "px";
}

update();

document.getElementById("update").addEventListener("click", update);
```

```css
.chart {
  width: 512px;
  height: 256px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin: 4px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>
<button id="update">Update</Button>
<div class="chart" id="container"><canvas id="chart"></canvas></div>
```

Comming from this github issue: https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/5409